# Erase files using the Gutmann method

Tags: linux, coreutils, delete

How can I erase a file using the Gutmann method?

Comment: If your HD is older than 2001 and smaler than 15GB, Gutmann method will be the proof of concept.

Answer (score 1):

[shred](https://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/manual/html_node/shred-invocation.html#shred-invocation) uses the Gutmann method.

There are several alternatives available for deleting files in a secure manner.

- See also: https://askubuntu.com/questions/57572/how-to-delete-files-in-secure-manner